# How to setup socket.io run on nextjs backend server on ubuntu server with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: next.js, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm making a chat app using nextjs and socket.io run on backend server. Everything work perfect when using at localhost in my windows computer. But when I upload it to ubuntu server, this don't work. I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy on ubuntu server, so that is my config of nginx:

```
server {

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name my_domain;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /api/socket/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sex69.lol/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sex69.lol/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Here is my server:
const io = new Server(res.socket.server, {
path: '/api/socket/',
addTrailingSlash: false,
pingInterval: 60000,
pingTimeout: 5000,
})

And client:
const socket = io(undefined, {
path: '/api/socket/',
})

Anything wrong with my setting?
Please help me!
Thanks!